# Getting XMLEdit to work for html extensions

Tags: html, vim

Hi I just started experimenting with the XMLedit plugin for vim (https://github.com/sukima/xmledit/). I've noticed that it works for xml file types and xhtml file types but doesn't work for html file types. How can I fix that?

I used the pathogen install.

Comment: The `readme` on that github page gives some instructions on using it with other file types, says that the documentation included with the plugin has additional information, and even specifically mentions having additional information for use with html files.

Comment: I agree with qqx but that's a strange idea to want to use an XML tool on something that's not XML.

Comment: From the documentation: _To add html support Sym-link or copy this file to html.vim in your ftplugin directory._ So, have you tried that?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the pathogen install was not working correctly. It didn't load the help files. So I built the vba and sourced it. This loaded the docs. Once I checked the docs I saw that there were two ways to get xmledit to work with html. I tried the simplier of the two-- sym-linking.

That worked.

Comment: Hi is this how you setup the symlink? ln -s html.vim xml.vim ( tried this but are getting a file exists )

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are correct, but it may not be clear to some. Here is the explanation:

From xmledit's [document](https://github.com/sukima/xmledit/blob/master/doc/xml-plugin.txt):

> To add html support Sym-link or copy this file to html.vim in your
>   ftplugin directory.

Here is what you may do:

```
# Assuming you are using vundle
$ cd ~/.vim/bundle/xmledit/ftplugin
$ ls
html.vim  php.vim  xhtml.vim  xml.vim
# The html.vim already exists, so we will change its name (or delete if you want)
$ mv html.vim html.vim.bk
# symlink
$ ln -s xml.vim html.vim
```

Comment: there's some small errors at the last line creating a symlink, the position of source file and target file is wrong, it should be the opposite `ln -s xml.vim html.vim`

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is incredibly confusing about what you should do.

If you installed it as a submodule using pathogen, your xmledit/ftplugin will look like:

```
 html.vim  php.vim  xhtml.vim  xml.vim
```

now html.vim contains code that you modify yourself with a callback so you can adjust the autocomplete if you so desire. However, a simpler solution is to delete html.vim and instead create a softlink:

```
ln -s xml.vim html.vim
```

this will apply the default tag completion rules to .html files