# How can I make closetag.vim automatic?

Tags: vim, tags, vim-plugin

Currently [closetag.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=13) only works with <kbd>Ctrl+_</kbd>
Is there a way so that I can make this automatic whenever I type  \<  ?

Comment: No idea, send an email to its author.

Comment: Does `:nmap \< <c-_>` not work?

Comment: @Noah it does not. I am tried a couple of other syntaxes, like `<lt>` instead of using \<, but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on closetag.vim and opted for [xmledit](https://github.com/sukima/xmledit/). In order to make it work with html files, I did the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101043/getting-xmledit-to-work-for-html-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
:imap <Leader><lt> <Esc><C-_>a
```

I hope you intended to trigger via <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd><</kbd>; just the second key would make it impossible to write any starting tag (unless you disable the mapping via `<C-V>`). Because closetag offers a *normal mode* mapping, you need to switch to normal mode first (and then re-enter insert mode).